# How to return number of items in a list in a defined data type with haskell

Tags: haskell

so with the defined data type

I am wondering how do you find the number of items in `list [b]` with a function.
e.g if `a = b 3 4 5 [c,d,e]`
This will return 3 with the function

```
Data b = b Int Int Int [b] deriving (Eq) 

kk :: b -> Int
```

sample input:

```
ghci> a = b 3 4 5 [b,c,d] 
ghci> kk a
3
```

Comment: `b` can not be a type, it is probably `data B = B Int Int Int [B]`. What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: aside from the fact that your code won't compile due to casing issues (the `data` keyword is all lowercase, type constructors and data constructors must start with an uppercase letter unlike the `b` that you've used for both), you do this by pattern matching to give a name to the list then using the `length` function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `b` can not be a type. A type starts with an uppercase. So the type is likely:

```
data B = B Int Int Int [B] deriving (Eq)
```

You can use pattern matching to "unpack" the data constructor. So here you can define a function:

```
kk :: B -> Int
kk (B a b c ds) = …
```

Where `a` will be the first item of the data constructor (so `3` in the sample data), `b` the second item (so `4` in the sample data), etc. I leave filling in the `…` as an exercise.